# How can I write an assertion to check the presence of a value in a second table with Minitest and Capybara?

Tags: capybara, minitest

I have two tables on a page. The second table is blank. When a link is clicked next to a value in the first table, that value is populated in the second table. It does not disappear from the first table.

How can I write an assertion to check that it has made it into the second table.

Both tables have ids.

I know how to do a `find` with `:xpath`, I just don't know how to `find` the value. I can `find` the new `:xpath`, but not the value.

Answer (score 0):

if using RSpec you can do

```
expect(page).to have_selector(:id, 'id of second table', text: 'text value you expect to appear in the table')
```

if not using RSpec it's

```
assert_selector(:id, 'id of second table', text: 'text value you expect to appear in the table')
```

If your question is that you don't know how to extract the value from the first table, then you'll need to provide an example of the html from that table.

Answer (score 0):

I was able nest the assertion inside a `within` block containing the `xpath`:

```
within(:xpath, '//*[@id="1"]/td[2]') do
  page.must_have_content("My Content")
end
```

Comment: What does must_have_content do that expect(page).to have_content(...) doesn't do?